# Is the manifold obtained by gluing along circles unique?

Tags: category-theory, manifolds, differential-topology

Consider a pair of embeddings $f,g : S^1 \rightarrow M$ in the category of topological manifolds with boundary. Assume $M$ is a surface with boundary, and that $f$ and $g$ land in the boundary, and thus have a coqualizer. I get the feeling that the coequalizer of $f$ and $g$ should be isomorphic to the coequalizer of $f$ and $g \circ h$, for any orientation-preserving homeomorphism $h:S^1 \rightarrow S^1$.

> **Question.** Is this correct, and if so, how does one prove it?
>
> Also, is there a standard name for this result?

Feel free to use smooth manifolds if you prefer.

Comment: Since $h$ is isotopic to the identity, you can construct the desired homeomorphism between the two co-equalizers by absorbing the isotopy into a collar neighborhood of $\text{image}(g)$ in $M$.

Comment: I cannot think of any special name, but it is a variation of a step of the proof of the well known theorem that connected sum is well-defined in the category of oriented manifolds.